# Make dropdown menu in css like in the picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have questions about how to reproduce the following:

[image]

I have the menu like this:

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*
/ nav
*/

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Decker';
}
nav:after {
  content: '';
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
nav ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: .6em;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 .5em;
}
nav li:last-child a:before {
  display: none;
}
nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.6em 0.6em 0.7em 0.6em;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
}
nav li a:before {
  content: "|";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: 1.6em;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-4%);
  transform: translateY(-4%);
  line-height: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  color: #fff;
}
nav li a:after {
  display: none;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #fac312;
  z-index: 2;
}
nav li a:hover {
  background: #b42024;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav li a.active {
  background: #b42024;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav li a.active:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #fac312;
  z-index: 2;
}
nav li a:hover:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="active">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

But, I don't know how to make the drop-down list like the picture shown above.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is as simple as a hidden box that will be visible at hover. But your problem will be the space between the menu and the dropdown, because that space will cause the end of the hover event and the box will hide.I think you need a transparent box in some way that handles that space.

Comment: how do you plan to add all options expected? divs? ul/li?

Comment: put all other elements in a div with background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);

Comment: @Bernhard: `background-color:transparent;` is faster. Gabriel, you seem to have two options: you learn `CSS` and code it yourself or you convince someone who already knows `CSS` to code it for you. Asking *"how do I do this?"* is really not convincing. Are you asking us to work for free? The only problem you seem to have is not allocating enough resources to the task at hand.

Comment: [Bootstrap v3 dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns). Use the example markup and make sure you load `bootstrap.min.js` after you load `jquery.min.js`. If you plan on using v4, you should search for it, read on how to get started and make sure you include `tether.min.js` before `bootstrap.min.js`. In two words: ***Search. Read.***

Comment: Why bootstrap? Why that suggestion? He only needs a box that is visible and hidden on hover and out respectively. He only needs some lines of CSS and a new html box. Why he needs two hundred javascript libraries?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude My problem is just there... I can do the drop down menu without problems, the problem is to leave it as the image above... Sorry for my English, my level in it is not so high and so sometimes I use the Google Translater...

Comment: @celerno I thought about using ul/li...

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I do not want it to work for me, I really appreciate the web development service. I need a way of how to do... I think I expressed myself badly. I managed to make the drop down menu, but it does not look like the image, below the second border. I'll edit my question with what I've done so far. Again, excuse me for misinterpretation and for my English... I'm not very good with it, and so Google Translator helps me... : D

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I'm already using the bootstrap... But I'm not getting the same result as the image :'(

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude because he was already using Bootstrap.

Comment: I don't know where did you see bootstrap (tag, code, comment, etc) before the last comment of @GabrielBontorin .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey This is what You want :) I hope

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
  position: relative;
}
nav:after {
  content: '';
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav__cat {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: .6em;
}

.nav__li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 .5em;
}
.nav__li:last-child a:before {
  display: none;
}
.nav__li:hover > a {
  background: red;
}
.nav__li:hover > a:after {
  display: block;
}
.nav__li:hover .sub__category {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav__li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25.6px 0.6em 0.7em 0.6em;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
}
.nav__li > a:before {
  content: "|";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: 25.6px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-4%);
          transform: translateY(-4%);
  line-height: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}
.nav__li > a:after {
  display: none;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ffaf1a;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sub__category {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.sub__category {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  margin: 0 .5em;
  padding-top: 25.6px;
  -webkit-transition: all .12s linear;
  transition: all .12s linear;
}

.sub__li {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px #000 solid;
  background: red;
}

.sub__link {
  padding: .7em 1em;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.sub__link:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul class="nav__cat">
  <li class="nav__li"><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li class="nav__li"><a href="">Menu 23</a>
   <ul class="sub__category">
     <li class="sub__li">
       <a href="#" class="sub__link">Subcategory</a>
     </li>
      <li class="sub__li">
       <a href="#" class="sub__link">Subcategory 2 </a>
     </li>
      <li class="sub__li">
       <a href="#" class="sub__link">Subcategory 3 </a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  <li class="nav__li"><a href="">Menu 345</a>
   <ul class="sub__category">
     <li class="sub__li">
       <a href="#" class="sub__link">Subcategory</a>
     </li>
      <li class="sub__li">
       <a href="#" class="sub__link">Subcategory 2 </a>
     </li>
      <li class="sub__li">
       <a href="#" class="sub__link">Subcategory 3 </a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  <li class="nav__li"><a href="">Menu 4567</a></li>
  <li class="nav__li"><a href="">Menu 56789</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is brilliant. I thank you from the heart for your help to this problem! I'm going to continue my studies and if I need to, I'll come back here!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you obviously will need some content in each of the menus!

Make sure to open this in the full page.

There is still a lot more styling work that needs to be done to achieve the result you want, but hopefully this helps you get moving in the right direction.

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*
/ nav
*/
nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Decker';
}

nav:after {
  content: '';
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav .mainmenu {
  /*display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;*/
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: .6em;
}

nav .firstlevel {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 .5em;
}

nav .firstlevel:last-child a:before {
  display: none;
}

nav .firstlevel a {
  width: 120px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.6em 0.6em 0.7em 0.6em;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
}

nav .firstlevel a:before {
  content: "|";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: 1.6em;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-4%);
  transform: translateY(-4%);
  line-height: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  color: #fff;
}

nav .firstlevel a:after {
  display: none;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #fac312;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav .firstlevel a:hover {
  background: #b42024;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav .firstlevel a.active {
  background: #b42024;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav .firstlevel a.active:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #fac312;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav .firstlevel a:hover:after {
  display: block;
}

.firstlevel{
  vertical-align: top;
}

.submenu_group{
  display:none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

li{
  list-style-type: none;
}

li .submenu{
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
}

.active:hover .submenu_group{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="mainmenu">
      <li class='firstlevel active'>
        <a href="" class="active">Home</a>
        <ul class='submenu_group'>
          <li>
            <a class='submenu'>first item</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class='submenu'>second item</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class='submenu'>third item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class='firstlevel'>
        <div>
          <a href="">About Us</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class='firstlevel'>
        <div>
          <a href="">Products</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class='firstlevel'>
        <div>
          <a href="">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: So close! Some improvements and it will be the answer

Comment: Yes, I don't have the time to do everything down to the last detail :)

Answer (score 0):

Here a fiddle of improved @Our_Benfactors answer
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ArefBenLazrek/6novgs5u/)

```css
  body {
    background: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  /*
  / nav
  */
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Decker';
  }

  nav:after {
    content: '';
    height: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    background: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  nav .mainmenu {
    /*display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;*/
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: .6em;
  }

  nav .firstlevel {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 .5em;
  }

  nav .firstlevel:last-child a:before {
    display: none;
  }

  nav .firstlevel a {
    width: 120px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1.6em 0.6em 0.7em 0.6em;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1;
  }

  nav .firstlevel a:before {
    content: "|";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    top: 1.6em;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-4%);
    transform: translateY(-4%);
    line-height: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: #fff;
  }

  nav .firstlevel a:after {
    display: none;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    background: #fac312;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  nav .firstlevel a:hover {
    background: #b42024;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  nav .firstlevel a.active {
    background: #b42024;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  nav .firstlevel a.active:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    background: #fac312;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .active .submenu_group a:after {
   background: transparent;
  }
  .active .submenu_group a {
   background:#b42024;
  }
  .active .submenu_group a:hover {
   background: #fff;
   color:#000;
   border-top: 2px inset #000;
   border-bottom: 2px inset #000;
  }
  .active .submenu_group li:first-child a:hover {
   border-top: 0;

  }
  nav .firstlevel a:hover:after {
    display: block;
  }

  .firstlevel{
    vertical-align: top;
  }

  .submenu_group{
    display:none;
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
  .active .submenu_group li:first-child a {
   margin-top: 28px;
  }
  .active .submenu_group a {
   padding: 10px;
  }
  .active:hover .submenu_group {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   background: #000;
  }
  li{
    list-style-type: none;
  }

  li .submenu{
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
  }

  .active:hover .submenu_group{
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
  <body>
    <nav>
   <ul class="mainmenu">
     <li class='firstlevel active'>
    <a href="" class="active">Home</a>
    <ul class='submenu_group'>
      <li>
     <a class='submenu'>first item</a>
      </li>
      <li>
     <a class='submenu'>second item</a>
      </li>
      <li>
     <a class='submenu'>third item</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='firstlevel'>
    <div>
      <a href="">About Us</a>
    </div>
     </li>
     <li class='firstlevel'>
    <div>
      <a href="">Products</a>
    </div>
     </li>
     <li class='firstlevel'>
    <div>
      <a href="">Contact</a>
    </div>
     </li>
   </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
```